# А как правильно по алфавитному порядку упорядочить следующие слова?

Tags: оформление-текста

А как правильно по алфавитному порядку упорядочить следующие слова? То есть, если есть пробел или дефис, что нужно делать-таки?

> Вьюга, в продолжении, в-третьих.

> В продолжении, вьюга, в-третьих.

> В-третьих, вьюга, в продолжении.

Comment: Лео, уточни, какой "алфавитный порядок" ты имеешь ввиду?